# Plsql - diff package in script with the one in db

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I want to redeploy a package with sqlplus like that:

```
echo exit| sqlplus user/passwd@db @package.sql
```

I wonder if it would be possible to diff @package.sql with the existing package in db(if exists at all).
I'm using power shell for that.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You may retrieve current package text with `dbms_metadata` package

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can do it using Power Shell. I'd

- install Notepad++

  - then install its "Compare" plugin
- use SQL Developer to easily access current package specification/body
- copy/paste it into Notepad++
- load package.sql into another Notepad++'s tab
- **compare** both tabs

  - you'd see which lines are equal, which exist in one tab and not in another (and vice versa) - everything

---

If you want to do it "automatically" while running package.sql ... then

1. I have no idea how to do it,
2. might cost more than what I suggested ("cost" because you'd have to develop a program which would do that, and that takes time and effort), unless there's already some tool which lets you do it (but I don't know anything about it)